# Reading cookie value in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I successfully set a cookie in JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000)); //one day expiration date
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
window.name = date.getTime();
document.cookie = "window_name="+window.name+expires+"; path=/";
```

Then in rails I try to read (I've tried both of the following):

```
cookies[:window_name]
request.cookies['window_name']
```

both of which have an empty value.
How can I access the window_name cookie that I set in the Javascript?

Comment: Have you verified that the cookie is actually being created by the JavaScript using a tool such as Firebug?

Comment: Yes, using Firebug and even displayed value from javascript 'alert' function.

Comment: In your controller, if your print out "cookies" is it in there?

Comment: Put a debugger in your controller or log the request object on the controller side, e.g. "my request #{@request.inspect}"

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, cookie with no value on the rails side...

It seems that cookies set with JavaScript need to be in the path of your controller.

Let say you want to use `cookies[:window_name]` in the users controller, you need to do :

```
document.cookie = "window_name="+window.name+expires+"; path=/users/";
```

Must be security stuff...
I don't what you could do if you want to use that cookie in several controllers, luckily I don't !