# Class cookie_jar undefined when Reading a cookie in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies

I have a problem when trying to read the content of cookies in ruby on rails. I set the content of the cookie inside a helper-class using `cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]`. I also can read the content with:

```
def user_from_remember_token
  User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end

def remember_token
  cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
end
```

The problem occurs when I call the method `user_from_remember_token` not from the corresponding view but from another class. Then inside of `remember_token` i get the error `undefined method 'cookie_jar' for nil:NilClass`. It seems that the class `cookies` can not be found. I also tried to put the whole code inside the Controller with no success. Furthermore I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567527/reading-cookie-value-in-rails).

Can there be a restriction that only views/helpers/controllers themselves can read the value of cookies that are defined by them?

Answer (score 0):

MVC stops cookies/session from getting into the model so this you have to send to it in a method from the controller.